# Cross Directional UIScrollViews - Can I Modify the Scrolling Behaviour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

**Here's how the scroll views work:** One scroll view is paging enabled in the horizontal direction. Each 'page' of this scroll view contains a vertically scrolling UITableView. Without modification, this works OK, but not perfectly.

**The behaviour that's not right:** When the user scrolls up and down on the table view, but then wants to flick over to the next page quickly, the horizontal flick/swipe will not work initially - it will not work until the table view is stationary (even if the swipe is very clearly horizontal).

**How it should work:** If the swipe is clearly horizontal, I'd like the page to change even if the table view is still scrolling/bouncing, as this is what the user will expect too.

**How can I change this behaviour - what's the easiest or best way?**

**NOTE** For various reasons, a UIPageViewController as stated in some answers will not work. How can I do this with cross directional UIScrollViews (/one is a table view, but you get the idea)? I've been banging my head against a wall for hours - if you think you can do this then I'll more than happily award a bounty.

Comment: What is your minimum iOS target? If iOS 6.0+, instead of using `UIScrollView`, have you considered using `UIPageViewController` here instead?

Comment: (Technically, you can use `UIPageViewController` from iOS 5.0+, yet I believe that `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` is only available starting iOS 6.0+)

Comment: @JRG-Developer I did consider UIPageViewController initially, but there's a few reasons it didn't work for me. I needed access to the scroll view's "scrollViewDidScroll:" method which isn't available for a page view.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish via `scrollViewDidScroll:` method? That is, there are similar delegate methods on `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`, such as `pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:` and `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:transitionCompleted:`, which would let you know that a horizontal scroll event was taking place.

Comment: @JRG-Developer a horizontal parallax like view effect - the methods in UIPageViewController delegate don't provide tracking information as scrolling occurs, only afterwards.

Comment: I'm going to try to mock this up. Are you using multiple controllers for the `UITableView` delegates and data sources (i.e. one controller manages each table view) or a single view controller acts as the delegate and data source for all table views?

Comment: @JRG-Developer ok great! It's a single view controller class, but multiple instances of it.

Comment: Hi, you can try contentOff for managing this....

Comment: @kokx what do you mean by contentOff? I assume you mean contentOffset? I'm well aware of what this property does, but I'm not sure how it's going to help in this case.

Comment: i means, use delegate function of scroll view and check contentOffset of scroll view, if it will move to page page then change it again to your existing page... Try it.. i have not tried it for your case but i have used it in my case and it is working fine....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to my understanding of the question, it is only while the tableView is scrolling we want to change the default behaviour. All the other behaviour will be the same.

SubClass `UITableView`. `UITableView`s are subClass of `UIScrollView`s. On the `UITableView` subClass implement one  `UIScrollView`'s `UIGestureRecognizer`'s delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    //Edit 1
    //return self.isDecelerating;
    //return self.isDecelerating | self.bounces; //If we want to simultaneous gesture on bounce and scrolling
    //Edit 2
    return self.isDecelerating || self.contentOffset.y < 0 || self.contentOffset.y > MAX(0, self.contentSize.height - self.bounds.size.height); // @Jordan edited - we don't need to always enable simultaneous gesture for bounce enabled tableViews
}
```

As we only want to change the default gesture behaviour while the tableView is decelerating.

Now change all 'UITableView's class to your newly created tableViewSubClass and run the project, swipe should work while tableView is scrolling. :]

But the swipe looks a little too sensitive while tableView is scrolling. Let's make the swipe a little restrictive.

SubClass `UIScrollView`. On the `UIScrollView` subclass implement another `UIGestureRecognizer`'s delegate method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        CGPoint velocity = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer velocityInView:self];
        if (abs(velocity.y) * 2 < abs(velocity.x)) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

We want to make the "swipe is clearly horizontal". Above code only permits gesture begin if the gesture velocity on x axis is double than on y axis. [Feel free to increase the hard coded value "2" if your like. The higher the value the swipe needs to be more horizontal.]

Now change the `UiScrollView' class (which has multiple TableViews) to your ScrollViewSubClass. Run the project. :]

[image]

I've made a project on gitHub https://github.com/rishi420/SwipeWhileScroll

Comment: Thank you! Just one small problem - when the table view 'bounces', the isDecelerating method seems to be set to no. For tables with a content height of less than the scroll view height this is an issue - is there a way around this at all?

Comment: I think bounces just tells you whether the scroll view can bounce or not, not actually whether it is currently bouncing. I've gone for: self.isDecelerating || self.contentOffset.y < 0 || self.contentOffset.y > MAX(0, self.contentSize.height - self.bounds.size.height);

Comment: This solution works pretty well, thanks! I'm gonna play a little bit more and see if I can make the table view keep scrolling while paging left and right, rather than stopping abruptly when the user does so.

Comment: Thanks. I thought we need to always enable simultaneous gesture for bounce enabled tableViews. Answer edited with your solution, Git updated also. Hey feel free to contribution on the git repository when you find the solution of "stopping abruptly".

Comment: After some playing, it works great on the simulator, but acts a little weirdly on an actual iOS device. To fix that I got rid of the second part of the solution - it seemed that if the user's pan wasn't quick enough, the velocity would be zero and hence panning wouldn't work. Functionally it's not exactly how I imagined it working (as both views can be scrolled simultaneously), but still does the trick!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Although apple doesn't like this method too much:

> **Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.**

I've found a great way to accomplish this.

This is a complete solution for the problem. In order to scroll the `UIScrollView` while your `UITableView` is scrolling you'll need to disable the interaction you have it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 0);
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        [data addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [_myTableView setContentOffset:_myTableView.contentOffset animated:NO];
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
          scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
          scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

To sum up the code above, if the `UITableView` is scrolling, set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` so the `UIScrollView` will detect the swipe. If the `UITableView` is scrolling and the user taps on the screen, `userInteractionEnabled` will be set to YES.

Comment: While your solution may work it might break in future releases. It is always a good idea to go with the docs ;)

Comment: @HAS I can't go with the docs if the OP question is initially against the docs. The apple quote refereed to the user question.

Comment: +1 on this solution. the docs do caution against it but I have an app in the App Store since iOS 4.x (now updated to iOS 7) that has `UITableView` objects inside a `UIScrollView` and my desired behavior has worked fine and Apple had no problem approving it. If some future iOS versions breaks it, I'll deal with it then. Until then, release your app and move on to other problems.

Comment: This is so close to the interaction I want, but only one problem. If the user wants to scroll the table twice in a row, then the second scroll of the table won't work until after the first scroll has finished decelerating. Is there a way to selectively choose whether user interaction is enabled or not depending on the pan direction?

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure what the purpose of the tap gesture recogniser is?

Comment: @Jordan The tap gesture will give you the `userInteractionEnabled` back. Without it you can't stop the `UITableView` from scrolling. Regarding your other question, I can think about a few ways to accomplish this, certain speed, certain gestures etc'. Nothing shouldn't be to hard if you'll follow the above basics.

Comment: @Sha If you can think of a few ways, are you able to describe/explain them? Maybe I'm missing something but I can't easily see a way :)

Comment: @Jordan That's pretty easy. Check if the user swipes up or down using a touch event or GestureRecognizer and set `userInteractionEnabled` to YES accordingly. Just like I did with `UITapGestureRecognizer` above.

Comment: @Sha it's not that easy - trying to check which direction seems to stop interactivity with the table view, so that the table view never receives the pan gesture that it should have.

Comment: @Jordan the interactivity shouldn't be stopped. I'll take a look at it when I'll get a chance.

Comment: i think this is great, but why not turn scrollview.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO instead of userInteractionEnabled ?? this way your views themselves will still work.  (i turn panGestureRecognizer on and off all the time in scrollViews for various things..)

Comment: Main issue with this method is that the user can't scroll vertically twice in a row without waiting till the table view stops moving - I haven't figured out a workaround. Unless that changes I'm gonna have to go with the solution posted (with the git hub project)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `UIScrollView` as a container for these multiple table views, try using a `UIPageViewController`.

You can even integrate this into your existing view controller setup as a `child view controller` (directly replacing the `UIScrollView`).

In addition, you'll likely want to implement the required methods from `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and possibly one or more of the methods from `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`.

Comment: I need access to scrollViewDidScroll: which is why I'm using a UIScrollView instead of a UIPageView. So still stuck in the same place. Good idea though - thanks.

Comment: You should be able to access the pan gesture recognizer of the UIPageViewController through its gestureRecognizers property, which should give the same information as scrollViewDidScroll: (writing from my phone so not 100% sure, but pretty sure)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the methods : `directionalLockEnabled` of both your table and scroll and set them up to horizontal for one and vertical for the other ?

**Edit :**

**1)**
What you want to do is very complicate since the touch wait some time (like 0.1s) to know what your movement will be. And if your table is moving, it will take your touch immediately whatever it is (because it's suppose to be reactive movement on it).

I don't see any other solution for you but to override touch movement from scratch to detect immediately the kind of mouvement you want (like if the movement will be horizontal) but it will be more than hard to do it good.

**2)**
Another solution I can advise you is to make your table have left and right margin, where you can touch the parent scroll (pages thing so) and then even if your table is scrolling, if you touch here, only your paging scroll will be touched. It's simpler, but could not fit with your design maybe...

Comment: Yes. You don't actually set directionalLockEnabled to a specific direction, it determines the direction after you have started scrolling and locks it to that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIPageViewController` and in the `-viewDidLoad` method (or any other method what best suits your needs or design) get `UIPageViewController`'s `UIScrollView` subview and assign a delegate to it. Keep in mind that, its delegate property won't be nil. So optionally, you can assign it to another reference, and then assign your object, which conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`, to it. For example:

```
id<UIScrollViewDelegate> originalPageScrollViewDelegate = ((UIScrollView *)[pageViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).delegate;
[((UIScrollView *)[pageViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]) setDelegate:self];
```

So that you can implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods with ease. And your `UIPageViewController` will call your delegate's `-scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

By the way, you may be obliged to keep original delegate, and respond to delegate methods with that object. You can see an example implementation in `ViewPagerController` class on my UI control project [here](https://github.com/monsieurje/ICViewPager)

Comment: Thanks! It turns out UIPageViewController has some other oddities that won't let me work past them... not small issues, so UIPageViewController won't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same thing recently. My `UIScrollview` was on paging mode and every page contained a `UITableView` and like you described it worked but not as you'd expected it to work. This is how solved it.

First I disabled the scrolling of the `UIScrollview`

Then I added a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the actual `UITableView` for left and right swipes.

The action for those swipes were:

```
[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currentPointX + 320, PointY) animated:YES];
//Or
[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currentPointX - 320 , PointY) animated:YES];
```

This works flawlessly, the only down side is that if the user drags his finger on the `UITableVIew` that will be considered as a swipe. He won't be able to see half of screen A and half of screen B on the same screen.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting! I actually need to be able to see half of each screen at a time unfortunately. I'll play around with this idea though and see if anything comes of it.

Comment: @Jordan I haven't tried it but you could use touch events to drag the `UITableView` with the same principle mentioned above. Sounds like a cool feature to test out.

Comment: the only problem with using touch events to control the table view offset is the inertia of the UITableView - that's no simple task, and it'd be very hard to get something replicating Apple's scroll view feel.

Comment: @Jordan The inertia can be controlled by the `UIScrollView` page scrolling. Swipe -> go to offset. Drag -> drag object. release-> check if x is bigger than current page/2 - if so, go to page +1 , else return to current page. All of this will be animated and will give a scroll view feel.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass your scroll view and your table views, and add this gesture recognizer delegate method to each of them...

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer    
     shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
                     (UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
        return YES;
   }
```

I can't be sure this is *exactly* what you are after, but it may come close.

Comment: Ah, have tried that, but this doesn't result in scrolling that is directionally locked sorry. Vertical pans should be for the table view, horizontal pans for the scroll view - rather than both at the same time.